# Retrieving get vars after slashes along with after interrogation mark

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I've been working with a .htaccess regex for an hour with no results so far. Help appreciated.

This is the original regex I have been using. It's repetitive, but it works

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]*)/*([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]*)/*([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]*)/*([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]*)/*([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]*) index.php?g1=$1&g2=$2&g3=$3&g4=$4&g5=$5 [NC,L]
```

Basically, it translates domain.com/url1/url2/url3... into get vars which are passed to index.php. Now, I would like to on top of getting those 5 vars, also get anything that is appended with a ?var=something. Example

```
http://www.domain.com/user($_GET['g1'])/profile($_GET['g2'])?msg=profileupdated($_GET['msg])
```

How can I update my regex to on top of g1, g2 up to g5, I can also retrieve the other custom get vars? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to send everything to `index.php` and let it handle the path and query etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a very easy solution for this

Append QSA to the regex like this, and it magically worked.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]*)/*([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]*)/*([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]*)/*([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]*)/*([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]*) index.php?g1=$1&g2=$2&g3=$3&g4=$4&g5=$5 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I was thinking the solution would be extremely complex, but QSA does the trick.

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA